# "Reference Error: $ not defined" Jquery in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm getting the error on the $(document).ready() function in my .js file. I've added the libraries and am working with an http-server. Not sure where else to search as I've tried all the solutions I've found online over the past few days. I recently moved from CodePen to VS Code.

This is the HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" href="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<title>Local Weather</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <div id="temp">
            <button onclick="cTemp()">C</button>
            <button onclick="fTemp()">F</button>
        </div>
            <div id="location"></div>
            <div id="weather"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the JS:

```
    var farTemp, celTemp;
var lat, long;

$(document).ready(function() {
    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

                // set variables to obtained location from above
                lat = position.coords.latitude;
                long = position.coords.longitude;

                // set JSON data to location variables, "lat" and "long" after converting to string for URL
                $.getJSON("https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=" + String(lat) + "&lon=" + String(long), function(json) {

                // temp variables and conversion rounded to nearest whole number
                farTemp = Math.floor(json.main.temp * 1.8 + 32);
                celTemp = JSON.stringify(Math.floor(json.main.temp));
                // output data
                document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = json.name;
                document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = farTemp;
                document.getElementById("weather").innerHTML = json.weather[0].description;
            }); 
        }); 
    }
}
});

// output temperautre in F
function fTemp() {
    document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = farTemp + "°F";
} // close fTemp
// output temperature in C
function cTemp() {
    document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = celTemp + "°C";
} // close cTemp
// get location

fTemp();
cTemp();
```

This is the CSS:

```
   .box {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #5c85d6;
  margin-top: 20%;
}

button {
  background-color: #79d2a6;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

Comment: What do you see in the console & network tab?

Comment: Have you called `$.noConflict()` somewhere?

Comment: I have not added $.noConflict(). 


And this is in the console: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/duclok/Documents/visualStudio/Local-Weather/script.js:4:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:640:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...

Comment: $.noConflict() doesn't seem to matter unless I'd like change '$' to 'Jquery'?

Comment: `$.noConflict()` reliquishes jQuery's hold on the `$` variable, which would result in the error you see. The error basically means that you are attempting to use jQuery before it has been loaded, yet the code in your question seems to be structured absolutely fine. Does the question accurately reflect the logic which results in this error?

Comment: I just didn't yet have knowledge of `$.noConflict()` yet. I'm wondering that since my code is formatted correctly, it's something to do with VS Code? As if I might need to add something else to handle the JQuery?

Comment: @KimDuclos did you find any resolution to this?